# non-singular transformation of a square matrix in an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $x$ be some vector. When $A$ is a square matrix, $A^*$ is the adjoint matrix of $A$, and $P$ is a non-singular matrix, is the inner product of $(A^{*}Ax,x)$ always identical to $(Ax,P^{-1}APx)$? If so, how can it be proved?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? When you are unsure if a statement is true or false, it is often useful to test it on some small examples.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{aligned}
1&=\left\langle\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}^\ast\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1\\ 0},\ \pmatrix{1\\ 0}\right\rangle\\
\ne0&=\left\langle\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1\\ 0},
\ \pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{1\\ 0}\right\rangle.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I understand well the equation doesn't always work out. I would be happy if you would know any particular condition where the equation works out.

Comment: @MASAdotoxine One sufficient condition for the equality to hold is that $A$ commutes with $P$. This is actually a necessary and sufficient condition when $A$ is nonsingular.

Comment: I could managed to prove that on my own. in order for $(Ax, Ax) = (Ax,P^{-1}APx)$ to hold, when $A$ is non-singular, the condition where $A$ can commute with $P$ is necessary and sufficient condition. The sufficient condition is obviously clear. necessary condition is proved as follow. In that case, $(Ax, Ax) = (Ax, P^{-1}APx)$ implies that $A^{*}A = A^{*}P^{-1}AP$. Since A is non-singular, by multiplying $A^{-1}$ both side by left, it implies that   $A = P^{-1}AP$, which is $PA =AP$.
Thank you very much for your help.